# [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500]

Tags: react-native, axios

Running a react native project with expo go on android while registering a new user I am getting this error.

1. Changed localhost to Ip address
2. Restarting the Server

```
const user = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    // send a post request to the backend
    axios
      .post("http://192.168.1.7:8000/register", user)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        Alert.alert(
          "Registration Successful",
          "You have Registered Successfully"
        );
        setName("");
        setPassword("");
        setEmail("");
      }) 
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert(
          "Registration Failure",
          "An error occurred during registration"
        );
        console.log("registraion failed", error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: looks like a problem with the web server. 500 is an HTTP internal server error, so your app is getting a response, but the server doesn't like it.